# await QueuedTask.Run(...) keeps QueuedTask busy for too long and QueuedTask.Run(...).Wait() hangs for arcgis pro

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro-sdk

If I use await QueuedTask.Run(..), it doesn't go to the next line, returns to the caller method and QueuedTask still remains busy

```
public void SetCustomPictureSymbol(ArcGIS.Desktop.Mapping.FeatureLayer featureLayer)
{
 SetFeatureLayerSymbolAsync(featureLayer, _symbol.Symbol);
 if (QueuedTask.Busy)
     Task.Delay(1000);
}

public async Task SetFeatureLayerSymbolAsync(ArcGIS.Desktop.Mapping.FeatureLayer 
ftrLayer, CIMSymbol symbolToApply)
{
 if (ftrLayer == null || symbolToApply == null)
     throw new System.ArgumentNullException();
 CIMSimpleRenderer currentRenderer = QueuedTask.Run(()=> ftrLayer.GetRenderer() as CIMSimpleRenderer).Result;
 if (currentRenderer == null)
     return;
 symbolToApply.SetRealWorldUnits(ftrLayer.UsesRealWorldSymbolSizes);
 currentRenderer.Symbol = symbolToApply.MakeSymbolReference();
 await QueuedTask.Run(()=> ftrLayer.SetRenderer(currentRenderer));
 if (QueuedTask.Busy)
 {
     Task.Delay(1000);
 }
}
```

And QueuedTask.Run(..) hangs when I use Wait() method

```
 public void SetFeatureLayerSymbolAsync(ArcGIS.Desktop.Mapping.FeatureLayer ftrLayer, CIMSymbol symbolToApply)
 {
 if (ftrLayer == null || symbolToApply == null)
     throw new System.ArgumentNullException();
 CIMSimpleRenderer currentRenderer = QueuedTask.Run(()=> ftrLayer.GetRenderer() as CIMSimpleRenderer).Result;
 if (currentRenderer == null)
     return;
 symbolToApply.SetRealWorldUnits(ftrLayer.UsesRealWorldSymbolSizes);
 currentRenderer.Symbol = symbolToApply.MakeSymbolReference();
 QueuedTask.Run(()=> ftrLayer.SetRenderer(currentRenderer)).Wait();
}
```